# Walking Moisture Farms

Tags: biology, xenobiology

JordanTheCynic here again with another question relating to my Eosi Humans.

Most of my questions are NSFW by the way so just a fair warning.

I made a post in the past which discussed how Eosi human females automatically start producing breast milk 24/7 at around 16 years of age and stop doing so when they hit 45, they can start producing breast milk earlier if they get pregnant at an earlier age. Overall, this results in the average Eosi human female producing 321,278 gallons worth of breast milk in a lifetime.

Many users pointed out the obvious issue that the Eosi Humans would need to indulge in an impossibly constant liquid intake to achieve such a high output of breast milk.

I think I might have come up with a possible solution to this issue but I don't know if it's scientifically accurate.

The current concept is to turn Eosi humans into walking ''moisture farms''. This means that their bodies automatically and constantly absorb moisture around them and recycle said moisture into the basic ingredients needed to produce either breast milk or semen ( based on the gender ) which their bodies produce in both high and constant amounts. Regularly ingested liquids are used to maintain basic organ functions in the body.

I don't think this would force Eosi humans to live in moist environments as they should be able to comfortably live with or without them but their bodies will undergo this natural moisture farming process whenever there is moisture in the air.

Could this concept work as a possible solution to the high outputs of breastmilk and semen?

If this is impossible, please forgive me. I am not good at biology.

Comment: Breast milk is also hugely expensive to make. Think of it as producing literal food with your body, because that's what it is to babies. Even if a moisture-farm-human *could* get enough fluids, they would also need to constantly eat to get enough nutrients in order to make the milk worthwhile - unless their babies are equipped to chug a *lot*.

Comment: @Zxyrra Speaking of which any engine will have limits in the amount of energy it can "produce" in any amount of time (e.g. you can't burn 1 ton of gasoline in 1600 ccm per day). In this  respect, a biological body is no different.

Comment: The moisture problem never stopped dairy farmers from milking cows every day. But methinks the problem will be when the female gets pregnant, and the competing demands on her blood nutrients between the fetus and the mammary glands. Which one would take priority?

Comment: Wouldn't it be lot simpler if they just **drank** lots of milk? You can give them a social custom of drinking milk from each other. Hard to see what else they'd need all that milk. Or otherwise give them a diet largely composed of liquids with lots of energy and protein?

Comment: Why is this getting VTCs for being "opinion-based"? The OP has provided a clear outline of an objectively flawed scenario that can therefore be objectively critiqued. Is this question discomforting? Yes. Is it opinion-based? Not particularly.

Comment: @Zxyrra it's a stupid and discomforting question which has only served to generate mockery at my embarrassingly lackluster knowledge of basic human biology. I myself am in favor of its removal.

Comment: @JordanTheCynic I would argue that at *least* half of questions asked on this site are fundamentally flawed. People ask questions to learn - it's ok to lack knowledge because the point of asking is to get it.

Comment: @Justin Thyme the Second: Doing some simple math has these Eosi humans producing a bit over 11,000 gallons of milk per year.  Per Google, the average dairy cow produces about 2500 gallons per year, and weighs 10-15 times as much as a typical healthy female human.  So you're looking at a milk production rate roughly 40-60 times that of dairy cows, which have been selectively bred for high production over centuries, if not millenia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The current concept is to turn Eosi humans into walking ''moisture farms''

That's un-possible.

The latent heat of vaporization for water is a whooping 2,260kJ/kg - this is the amount of energy one Eosi human will need to extract from water vapors to liquefy it. Given that the average human energy intake per day is 8700 kilojoules and the efficiency of the biological processes-against-entropy is low, probably your "human-as-a-moisture-farm" will spend all its energy condensing about 0.3-0.5 kg of water per day and do nothing else, so you can forget that milk.

Comment: In that case, should I just ignore the science and go pure fantasy?

Comment: Or add a supplement of energy in other forms.

Comment: what other types of supplemental energy can be used?

Comment: Whatever energy the heat pumps use.

Comment: I am confused. How do those little absorbent pads thy put in electronics boxes absorb so much moisture?

Comment: @justinthyme Because they are dessicated before you put them there. Try to get the water they absorbed out from them (to use for other purposes) and you'll understand their use-case.

Comment: I have seen them dripping water.

Comment: That means your electronics were dripping water too, those pads exhausted their absorbance capacity.

Comment: See also [hygroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygroscopy).

Comment: @JordanTheCynic: No, successfull fantasy requires the willing suspension of disbelief.  Few people are capable of suspending their disbelief that much.

Comment: @jamesfq It **is possible** to generate that horny species that he wants, without _too much_ handwaving and on plausible biosciency+SciFi bases (even more, from a Homo Sapiens root). It's not trivial, but possible. Not by atmospheric moisture condensation though.

Comment: @jamesqf there is a colossal amount of terrible erotica out there that says otherwise.

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi  from your reference ' Unlike hygroscopy, however, deliquescence involves absorbing sufficient water to form an aqueous solution.' and 'Thorny dragons collect moisture in the dry desert via nighttime condensation of dew that forms on their skin and is channeled to their mouths in hygroscopic grooves between the spines of their skin. Water also collects in these grooves when it rains. Capillary action allows the lizard to suck in water from all over its body.'

Comment: @Starfish Prime: Well, I wouldn't know about that.  Note that I said "few people", not "no one" :-)